# El Css debe aplicarse cuando NO existe etiqueta

Tags: css

quiero hacer que se ponga un background color cuando dentro de los `<li>` no exista el `<a>`, este background sólo debe aplicarse al `<li>` que no tiene ese

```
<a>



<style>

    #myId > li:not(a){
     background-color:red;
    }

  </style>

</head>


<body>


      <ul id="myId">

      <li>
      <a href="">1</a> 
      </li>


       <li>
         2
       </li>


       <li>
        <a href="">3</a> 
      </li>


      </ul>
      <br>
        <ul>

      <li>
      <a href="">4</a> 
      </li>


       <li>
         5
       </li>


       <li>
        <a href="">6</a> 
      </li>


      </ul>

    </body>
```

El problema que estoy encontrando es que pone el rojo a todo el UL porque ha encontrado un `<li>` sin `<a>`

Por ejemplo para el segundo `<ul>` hay un li sin a, pero a ese no se debe aplicar, es decir, aplicar un estilo al li que no tenga a que esté dentro dentro de un identificador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías subir el CSS que usas? Tiene pinta de que vas a necesitar Javascript para poder hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: ¿Y si le das una vuelta? Podrías dar a todos los `li` el color de fondo y a todos los `li a` quitarselo con un none.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes. No existe un selector para ver si un elemento "tiene dentro" otro. Solo puedes recorrer el arbol CSS DOM hacia arriba , es decir "esta dentro de" o hacia a los lados (y solo en sentido descendente en el marcado html) con "~" .
Lo que estas haciendo con `li:not(a)`es seleccionar los `<li>` que no son `<a>`, no tiene sentido. 
Como ya han comentado, tendras que usar js o resolverlo de otra manera.

Si en vez de meter la cantidad directamente como lo has hecho la pones en un contenedor, una `<p>`por ejemplo, si que podrias hacer algo como:

```
li a{background:white}
li p{background:red}
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, lo plantearé de otro modo.

Comment: he editado un poco con una alternativa sencilla

Answer (score 1):

```html
<style>

    li {
      background-color: red;    
    }
    
    ul a{
     background-color:white;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     float: left;
    }

  </style>

</head>


<body>


      <ul id="myId">

      <li>
      <a href="">1</a> 
      </li>


       <li>
         2
       </li>


       <li>
        <a href="">3</a> 
      </li>


      </ul>
      <br>
        <ul>

      <li>
      <a href="">4</a> 
      </li>


       <li>
         5
       </li>


       <li>
        <a href="">6</a> 
      </li>


      </ul>

    </body>
```

No podrías usar el `not()` para hacer eso. Pero podrías conseguir ese efecto de otra manera. Puedes poner que todos los `<li>` tengan ese color rojo de fondo y hacer que las etiquetas `<a>` tengan el blanco y que además ocupen el 100% del tamaño que ocupa su padre (los `<li>` en nuestro caso) Así, cuando dentro de un `<li>` exista un `<a>` tape el color rojo de fondo, ocasionando que solamente las que no lo tengan se presenten en rojo.

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo y la explicación, de todos modos, 5 no se debería pintar en rojo, le daré otro enfoque, gracias.

Comment: Cinco se pinta de rojo porque no tiene etiqueta **a** dentro. Si solo quieres que se pinten de rojo los **li** que no tengan un enlace dentro y que pertenezcan al primer **ul** (me fijé que le tienes puesta una ID) puedes modificar la regla CSS para que solo afecte a los **li** de cuyo padre tenga esa ID, en vez de a todos los **ul**.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por responder, al final lo resolví usando js.

```
function addColor(){
  var elements = document.getElementById("myId");  // cojo todos los elementos 

  for (var i=0;i<elements.children.length; i++){
    var myLi = elements.children[i]; // Recojo el li

    if(myLi.children.length == 0 ){ // Si el li no tiene <a> le pongo una clase
        myLi.className = "colorRojo";
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Vaya, no había visto que ya habías usado JS y te lo dejé con jQuery. Bueno, ahí queda para el futuro jejejeje. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Por si te animas a usar jQuery te dejo esto que funciona:

Código jQuery

```
$('#myId li a').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').css('background-color','white')

})
```

Código CSS:

```
#myId li {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Aquí te dejo el enlace funcionando. [Pincha](https://jsfiddle.net/Emerita/m8xpgzwa/4/)